# CustomView inside recycler view not showing keyboard when focus

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-edittext, android-custom-view, android-softkeyboard, android-inputtype

I have created one custom view that extends constraintsalyout. Inside that view, I added EditText and Textview. When I try to add this custom view inside recycler view, Its not showing keyboard when I touch on that edittext.

Its perfectly working when added outside of recycler view

```
public class SVEditText extends ConstraintLayout {

private Context context;
private EditText editText;
private TextView textView;

public SVEditText(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sv_edittext, this);
    editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SVEditText);
    editText.setText(typedArray.getString(R.styleable.SVEditText_text));
    editText.setHint(typedArray.getString(R.styleable.SVEditText_hint));
    editText.setLines(typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.SVEditText_android_lines, 1));
    editText.setInputType(typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.SVEditText_android_inputType, 0));
    textView.setText(typedArray.getString(R.styleable.SVEditText_title));
    setDrawablesToEditText(typedArray);

    typedArray.recycle();
}

private void setDrawablesToEditText(TypedArray typedArray){
    if (typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.SVEditText_android_lines, 1) != 1){
        Drawable innerDrawableLeft = typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.SVEditText_iconLeft);
        Drawable innerDrawableRight = typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.SVEditText_iconRight);
        GravityCompoundDrawable iconLeft = null, iconRight = null;
        if (innerDrawableLeft != null) {
            iconLeft = new GravityCompoundDrawable(innerDrawableLeft);
            innerDrawableLeft.setBounds(0, 30, innerDrawableLeft.getIntrinsicWidth(), innerDrawableLeft.getIntrinsicHeight()+30);
            iconLeft.setBounds(0, 0, innerDrawableLeft.getIntrinsicWidth(), innerDrawableLeft.getIntrinsicHeight());
            iconLeft.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        }
        if (innerDrawableRight != null) {
            iconRight = new GravityCompoundDrawable(innerDrawableRight);
            innerDrawableRight.setBounds(0, 30, innerDrawableRight.getIntrinsicWidth(), innerDrawableRight.getIntrinsicHeight()+30);
            iconRight.setBounds(0, 0, innerDrawableRight.getIntrinsicWidth(), innerDrawableRight.getIntrinsicHeight());
            iconRight.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        }

        editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(iconLeft,
                null, iconRight, null);
        editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_edit_multiline);
        return;
    }

    editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.SVEditText_iconLeft),
            null, typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.SVEditText_iconRight), null);
}

public void setText(String value){
    editText.setText(value);
}

public void setHint(String hint){
    editText.setHint(hint);
}

public void setTitle(String title){
    textView.setText(title);
}

public void setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( @DrawableRes int left, @DrawableRes int top, @DrawableRes int right, @DrawableRes int bottom){
    editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
}

public void setText(Spannable spannable) {
    editText.setText(spannable);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the mistake I made.
I missed this line in xml.

`android:inputType="phone"`

So it is taken as 0 default from my custom view code.
I updated that default value as 1, now it is working without adding inputtype in xml.